# Entity having two entities of the same type

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship, database-schema

I'm programming a small game and a database representing Players and Matches.

A player has a name, a player ID and a rank.
A match has an ID, and two players.

Player

- * id (bigint)
- name (string)
- playerID (string)
- rank (integer)

Match

- * id (bigint)
- matchID (string)
- playerOne (Player)
- playerTwo (Player)

I would like to have a "matches" relationship in a Player, but how do I have an entity having two entities of same type and what type relationship should I use?

I tried a one-to-one relationship, but the UNIQUE condition it created is a problem.

Comment: A good way to figure out relationships is to talk out loud. In your case you should say "A player can play multiple matches" and "A match can have multiple players" which translates into `ManyToMany`.
If it was a `OneToOne`, you would say "A player can only play one match" and "A match can only include one player" (unless you add multiple `OneToOne` to `Player` but that's not flexible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to easily find all matches per player you will need to use a `ManyToMany` relationship. The following is a simplified snippet of what the classes would look like.

```
class Player {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="players")
     */
    protected $matches;

}

class Match {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Player", inversedBy="matches")
     */
    protected $players;

}
```

Then you run the following command from the root directory:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Your/AwesomeBundle/Entity
```

And you will be able to use methods such as:

```
Match::getPlayers()
Match::addPlayer()
Player::addMatch() // probably will have an 'e' at the end of the word match
Player::getMatches() // which is the one that will give you all matches of a user
```

You will need to restrict the number of players per match in your code.

Comment: This is the right answer. If you need to store some additional information (ex. winner, player order) you can store them in the linked table, and use 2 many-to-one relations (not real many-to-many) as suggested by PeteGO. In conclusion having a single players relation (instead of player1 and player2) is surely the way to go.

Comment: This answer helped to understand the process, but please, don't use PHP static methods syntax, it's really disturbing.

Comment: Sorry Cyril, I understand your point of view, I only use this syntax because it is used on the official PHP documentation otherwise I totally agree it could be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You need a many-to-many relationship.  This is usually done with a "middle" or "link" table.  In this example the `PlayedMatch` table is the link table.

This is effectively a single many-to-many relationship between Player and Match.  However it is represented by 2 one-to-many relationships :

Player [1] --> [n] PlayedMatch

Match [1] --> [n] PlayedMatch

```
Player
  Id
  Name
  Rank

Match
  Id

PlayedMatch
  Id
  MatchId
  Player1Id
  Player2Id
```

I see you've got some string properties named PlayerId and MatchId.  Avoid these names if you can because they are usually used for foreign key relationships.

You would probably want some more properties in the `PlayedMatch` table like `WinnerId` (linking to Player).

A SQL query on the above would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  PlayedMatch pm
    INNER JOIN Player p1 ON pm.Player1Id = p1.Id
    INNER JOIN Player p2 ON pm.Player2Id = p2.Id
    INNER JOIN Match m ON pm.MatchId = m.Id
```

Comment: Interesting, so what will be the relationships between these three entities. Probably a manytomany between Player and PlayedMatch, and a onetoone between Match and PlayerMatch? Any tip of how to do this in Symfony ?

Comment: Actually this is really just 1 many-to-many relationship between Player and Match.  Technically it is represented by 2 one-to-many relationships.  I'll update my answer with some more details.

Comment: You are right. But the real problem here is how to maintain "matches" relation on player entity (not raw sql), meaning how to get all matches for a player, regardless was he player1 or player2. With this kind of schema, I don't think there is a nice solution in Doctrine/Symfony. Of course, you could have 2 relations, matchesAsPlayer1 and matchesAsPlayer2, and another method that merges the two.